# autofill cells with star when first cell filled by content

Tags: microsoft-excel

i have a table of contents in excel. i want each time i fill first cell with any text or number B2,C2 and D2 be filled by a star. so i can change which cell with any content or leave some them alone.

Comment: So.. you don't know how to write an =IF... formula in B2, C2 and D2 respectively? Like `=IF(A2="";"";"*")` ?

Comment: @LPChip yes unfortunately i do not know many in excel. also i want to do this if for many rows. should i put IF(A2="";"";"*") in each cell?

Comment: @LPChip ok i have tried that. i have put formula in one cell and drag that to down now it work fine. thank u.

Comment: i have another question. i have a cell for sum. but stars makes error. how count star as zero? or non number = 0? thanks...

Comment: the SUM function already doesn't consider non-value cells... stars should not give errors

Comment: Use SUMIF. This formula allows a certain expression to be validated before it will apply the sum. Alternatively, create a new column and on each cell add a 0 or the number depending on what is in your B, C and/or D column. Alternatively, replace the * with a 0 instead. Note, you can use conditional formatting to make the 0 invisible or change the cell's color.

Comment: @LPCHIP can you please send an answer and explain complete? i want to select your answer.

Comment: Done. Took a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll see if I understood correctly what you want, based on the question and comments.

On cells B2, C2 and D2 respectively, you will want to put the following formula:

```
=IF(A2="";"";0)
```

This will place a 0 these cells if A2 contains nothing, and remove it if A2 contains something unless you overwrite the cell with your own number.

Select columns B, C and D at the top, and apply a darker background color to them. Optionally also change the foreground to the same color (hide)

Now, with the selection still in tact, press Conditional Formatting (located in the Start tab), select if this cell is exactly "" and give it the background color white. (you have to change it to white, or it will not alter the background color).